# Blur event handler in Angular 2 components

Tags: angular, events, blur

Has anyone tried to define a handler for `blur` events outside of HTML template?

Looks like `(blur)="doSomething()"` is the only way to go, because

```
@HostListener('blur', ['$event'])
doSomething(){

}
```

won't not work (at least for me), neither will `host` property in the decorator config (putting aside the fact that it has apparently been discouraged).

Can this be confirmed?

Comment: This just works. Either your component is not even instantiated or the elemen't doesn't emit a `blur` event.

Comment: I am getting similar issue. Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: Having the similar issue. blur doesn't work. focusout does, but then I have other issues.

Answer (score 0):

HostBinding is used to bind to host properties and [HostListener](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/HostListener-interface.html) is for events. The [style guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#06-03) has a fuller explanation.

Comment: sorry, I wrote it by "free hand" - this is an obvious mistake. HostListeners is what I have been trying!